# how to close and start a program from cmd in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe, process, task-manager, telnet

I've been trying cmd commands such as "**taskkill**" on Windows XP and apparently they don't exist.

I'd like to be able to close and open a program from the cmd because I need to connect to the Windows XP through a Telnet connection. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

`taskkill` is not available in Windows XP Home systems. You should use `tskill` instead.

[SOURCE](https://www.computerhope.com/tskill.htm)

Comment: When using interactively, an important difference is that `taskill` without the `/f` option is capable of sending WM_CLOSE to cleanly exit the program; `tskill` goes straight for the kill.

Comment: I get the same message saying that tskill is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc. Maybe I need to enable something? Also, to do this, I would need the PID and a way to get that PID from the cmd, which I also don't know for Windows XP.

Comment: @itd exactly what edition and versions of Windows XP are you using?  Are they Home or Pro? Are they up to date with latest service packs installed?

Comment: @Mokubai it's Windows XP Embedded, version 2002, service pack 2...

Comment: @itd that information should be in your question as it is crucial. IIRC XPe can be configured to leave out pretty much all unnecessary tools so all bets are off concerning what *should* be available. You might have to upload your own tools to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to start a programme in cmd in XP is the same as later versions of Windows:
Change the directory and run the programme: 
For instance: You have a programme called TSpin.exe under: c:\MyApps

```
cd c:\MyApps
TSpin.exe
```

I saw somewhere else mentioning another way of starting a programme in XP:

```
subfolder\program to run.exe
```

I've not tried this myself.